# How to conditionally pause Kafka-connect connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Confluent Kafka JDBC connector to retrieve data from various sources. I am interested to show preview before processing all records from datasource. For that, I am expecting to pause connector automatically after fetching 100 records. Currently I am using the following REST API to pause the connector after 5 min.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/references/restapi.html#put--connectors-(string-name)-pause

Is it any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Kafka Connect isn't really meant to be used like this, but you could fork the JDBC connector code, and add a blocking loop over the ResultSet to log the values, I guess... But how exactly are you guaranteed to only get 100 DB events every 5 minutes?

Comment: Thats the problem in my case. For large dataset takes more than 5 minutes to retrieve 100 records. So that only I am expecting Kafka to pause the connector automatically after 100 messages in topic

Comment: It won't pause the connector, but the consumer poll loop could be manipulated in some way, accordingly to the properties provided to it. Otherwise, it's just spinning on an infinite loop, keep getting zero records

Comment: Can you try to use Futures(while making db call) for the same, so unless your future gets completed don't poll?